# Port seems to be in use although the corresponding process has already terminated on AIX 6.1

Tags: port, aix

While running some kind of automated tests on our AIX 6.1 machine we are facing the problem that a port seems to be in use although the corresponding process has already terminated.

E.g. if we kill a hanging application using port 9999 we’ll get the following:

```
user@aix:~/EP$ netstat -Aan | grep 9999
…
f1000700149ec3b0 tcp        0      0  *.9999             *.*                LISTEN
…
user@aix:~/EP$ rmsock f1000700149ec3b0 tcpcb
Wait for exiting processes to be cleaned up before removing the socket
```

Currently, we only can recover from this state by rebooting the machine.

We already tried to set SO_REUSEADDR but we still get this strange kind of error.

The error is not application specific - it happens with different applications.

```
user@aix:/etc$ oslevel -s
6100-04-01-0944
```

Comment: How are you killing the processes? Are you sure they have actually died, and aren't zombies (or just taking a while to exit)?

Comment: We are killing the process with kill -9. When listing the processes using ps the process is not available anymore.

Comment: Terminating process by SIGKILL (9) leaves ports open / they will be freed first after timeout... the time depends on your system configuration (usually several hours). Consider using a proper way to terminate your app.

Comment: Hi, i am a colleague of Stefan. The processes are killed with -9 after a normal shutdown of the application has been tried and did not work. This is a kind of fallback to make sure the processes are gone after testruns. This is working on all other platforms we are using (linux, solaris, windows, hp-ux, z-linux). @Kamil: How can this timeout be configured on aix, or is there a way to explicitely close those ports?

Comment: @Ron I'm not AIX expert, but rmsock could help to free the port

Comment: rmsock is exactly what we have tried if you look at my first posting ...